# How to generate a ring network in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Using the Netlogo Networks extension nw:generate-ring will generate a ring network of turtles, in which each turtle is connected to exactly two other turtles.

How could I create a ring network in which each turtle is connected to exactly X (an even number) other turtles please? So maybe it's closest 3 neighbours in the ring on either side for X=6.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the nw:generate-ring to get you started then ask all the turtles to create links with turtles within some distance using nw:turtles-in-radius